# Stopping and starting aws ec2 caused my website to stop working

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I stopped and started my instance because it had run out of memory now I'm unable to connect to it at all using 52.1.77.76 address. I also tried a sudo reboot but that didn't fix the issue either. Before stopping and starting my website was running fine. Also the status checks are fine and it's the same IP as before. I'm wondering if i need to start a service or something like that again from the ssh.

I'm also wondering if i need to change from micro to small and how to do that so I won't run out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that its public IP has not changed?

If your EC2 instance is EC2-Classic (not EC2-VPC) then both the public and private IP addresses for the instance are released when you stop the instance. When you restart the instance, new IP addresses are assigned.

If your EC2 instance is EC2-VPC and you stop it then the private IP is retained but the public IP is released. A new public IP is assigned when the instance restarts.

If you have an Elastic IP address associated with the instance then:

- if the instance is EC2-Classic then the Elastic IP is disassociated
- if the instance is EC2-VPC then the Elastic IP is retained

For more, see the documentation on [Stopping and Starting Your Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html#starting-stopping-instances). Basically you need to stop the instance, then resize it by changing the instance type.

On the topic of changing your instance from micro to small, see [Resizing Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html).

Comment: I'm using a EC2-VPC with Elastic IP and I'm pretty certain the IP is the same. I'm using the same putty window and didn't change any settings

Comment: So you can SSH to it, but connecting to port 80 is refused? Is your web server actually running? On the instance itself, what happens if you curl localhost:80?